# Does 3d vector lay in 4 sided pyramid?

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry

I have a question I didn't find an answer to on google or the forum and decided to ask here for help.

I am a fairly seasoned programmer and have had many successes on various platforms but I didn't use/need a lot of mathematics until now.

Now I need to know how to build a function which receives an array of 5 points (4 sided pyramid) and a single vector. The Question is whether this 3d vector lays inside of the pyramid.

The function would ultimately be written in (Mono) C# but if you have hints or code for other languages or you can help with plain mathematics that would be absolutly fine, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vector never lays inside anything. I guess you meant that you have a 3D point, not a 3D vector.

In that case, a simple solution (that works for any convex polyhedron) is to check whether your point is on the correct half spaces when considering each face of your pyramid.

Specifically, take two vectors in the first face of your pyramid (e.g., two edges) and form a third vector with one point on this face (e.g., one of the vertices) and the point to be tested. Using the sign of the mixed product (i.e., take the cross product of the two edges, which results in a vector orthogonal to the pyramid face, and check with a dot product whether this normal is in the same direction as your third vector), you can determine on which side your point is.

Repeating the procedure for all faces allows you to conclude.

Comment: Thanks! I just came up with a solution circumventing the issue, but as long as you gave the solution here I will mark it as such ;)